# css: horizontally center floated image gallery

Tags: css

I have a gallery-like list of block items with text content.  The text content is aligned to the bottom with using display: table* stuff.  The list is not fixed width, as it expands to the viewport width by creating more columns.  I want to center the list on the screen, such that the bottom row will still be aligned with the left of all other rows (one reason I couldn't figure out how to use inline-block).  Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
            ul{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                list-style: none;
            }
            ul:after{
                display: block;
                clear: both;
                content: ' ';
            }
            li{
                display: table;
                float: left;
                border: 1px solid red;
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
            }
            .gridRow{
                display: table-row;
            }
            .gridCell{
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: bottom;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">1</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">2</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">3</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">4</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">5</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">6</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">7</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">8</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">9</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">10</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">11</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">12</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">13</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">14</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">15</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">16</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">17</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">18</span></span></li>
            <li><span class="gridRow"><span class="gridCell">19</span></span></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the UL a width or put it in a containing element with a width and "overflow:auto;".

The width can be in px or in %.

Then give the container a margin of "margin:0 auto;"

Then you simply set your LI elements as "display:inline-block;" or give them "float:left;"

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jDqbJ/1/

```
.container {
 width:75%;
 overflow:auto;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.container ul li {
 float:left;width:75px;
 height:75px;
 background:#ccc;
 margin:0 10px 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: Notice in your example what happens when the container expands to 100%, or you make the boxes 300px wide.  The 'width' of the list is supposed to be the apparent width of the list based on the number of columns that fit in the viewport.  So with my example, if the viewport is 900-1199 pixels wide, the list will be 900px wide, and then centered in the 900-1199 pixel space.  I could use media queries for every imaginable breakpoint to do this and then margin auto would work, but that would be annoying.

Comment: I think you'll need a javascript based solution.

Comment: Darn.  Just going the media query route then, not to worried if IE8- have it aligned left.  If we used a preprocessor, I could output a bunch of break points easily, but since it's straight CSS, I went with up to 6 columns